# Inheritance of EntityTypeConfiguration across different Projects in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a 'master' Visual Studio project which contains Entity Framework mappings similar to:

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        // Table Mapping
        ToTable("Users");
        this.Property(x => x.Username).HasColumnName("Username");


        // Other mapping goes here
    }
}
```

The `User` entity being mapped is just a simple POCO:

```
 public class User {
     public string Username { get; set; }

     // Other properties omitted for brevity
 }
```

I have a second 'child' VS project/application (which references the master project) which has the following `ExtendedUser` Entity/POCO which is also mapped using EF:

```
public class ExtendedUser : User {

     // Extra navigation properties
     public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

This entity doesn't have extra fields, but does have various relationship collections which are specific to that application and only that application.

My problem is that I would like to inherit the mapping defined for the `User` in the first VS project.  The master `User` class is going to be used in several other projects so I need to avoid any duplication of mappings.

If I define the mapping as:

```
public class ExtendedUserMap : UserMap
{
    public UserMap()
    {

    }
}
```

Then I can't reference any of the `ExtendedUser` properties as the mapping is of type `EntityTypeConfiguration<User>` not `EntityTypeConfiguration<ExtendedUser>`.

Obviously I can't inherit from two classes, so I am unsure of a suitable way to achieve what I want to do.

How can I define `ExtendedUserMap` such that I can use the `User` mappings and also include the navigation properties for `ExtendedUser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your base mapping class slightly different:

```
public abstract class UserMapBase<TUser> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TUser>
    where TUser : User
{
    protected UserMapBase()
    {
        // Table Mapping
        ToTable("Users");
        this.Property(x => x.Username).HasColumnName("Username");


        // Other mapping goes here
    }
}
```

Now you can have a subclasses like so:

```
public class UserMap : UserMapBase<User>
{ }

public class ExtendedUserMap : UserMapBase<ExtendedUser>
{
    public ExtendedUserMap()
    {
        // map ExtendedUser properties here.
    }
}
```